# Can't upgrade TL neither update SP

Tags: aix

We got an AIX server with default installed with 6100-06-12-1339 update - from oslevel -s command.

When I do try to go with smit suma I only got the information : 
0500-059 Entitlement is required to download.
The system's serial number is not entitled.
Please go to the Fix Central website to download fixes.

Now going to page downloading TL07 and appropriate SP is not a problem - just a lot of *.bff files downloaded.

I did copy them to folder /tmp/a - yeah I knew the magic name :). 
Created a .toc file on this folder with inutoc /tmp/a.
The file is there and contains all information about the updates involved.

Now starting smit update_all or smitty doesn't do a thing. The main difference is that smit update_all is saying that everything is already on same level or higher - which btw it's not. And smitty itself is constantly complaining about like 30 out of 700 updates have missing dependencies which btw are not because I did download them all from the IBM official page - every possible update.

I can go to the outside world - since there's information back from update server so I can only assume that's not an issue. Please help.

Comment: Did you download a SP for TL7 that was released before TL6 SP 12? Check the 4 digits at the end.

Comment: Yes Sir I did, Ibm was cool enough to provide "requirements" for tl and attach them to TL itself.

Comment: You can't install an SP that's older than the one you have, even if it's a newer TL; choose a later service pack.

Comment: so what you are saying is that I should right now try to get newest available SP (like 10 versions higher than the one which is by default with TL07) with all prerequisites and install them, then try to push with TL07?

Comment: I don't know what you *should* do, I'm just saying it sounds like you were trying to do something that AIX prevents you from doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were trying to install AIX 6.1 TL7 with a service pack lower than 9, then you would be trying to apply patches that were *older* than AIX 6.1 TL 6 SP 12.

See: 
https://www-304.ibm.com/webapp/set2/sas/f/best/aix_service_strategy.pdf

under "AIX Level Naming" to see the build sequence identifier at the end. AIX 6100-06-12 has a sequence ID of 1339; to get a sequence ID higher than that in TL7, you'd have to select SP 9 (1341) or SP 10 (1415).

Also in that PDF, under "Other considerations", it says:

> When moving up to a new Technology Level, you must move to a Service
>   Pack that has the same or later Build Sequence Identifier than your
>   current Service Pack. The Service Pack number itself will not be the
>   same, because the Service Packs will be numbered consecutively as they
>   are released, but the dates will tell you where you need to be on the
>   new Technology Level. The update process will not allow an earlier
>   built Service Pack to be applied to avoid the chance of regression.

See the releases and their sequence IDs at:
https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/aix/selectFixes?release=6.1&function=release

Comment: Thank you. I can't give you up points yet cause of my counter is too low, but appreciate this, your time and effort.

Comment: If this has identified (and/or solved) your problem, feel free to use the checkmark next to it so that the Question is marked as Answered. Thank you!

Comment: well it didn't completely but gave a very good view on some things, because for example you cannot put sp with number you gave because TL is prerequisite for them so it's really closed circle but on my way to find precise solution :) ....... good times

Comment: well if someone will be reading this solution was download all bff files from TL08 I used ftp option from IBM - and then there are two packages inside which are inside in "broken" state  X11.fnt.ucs.ttf and X11.fnt.ucs.ttf-CN. So solution was to even though they are broken according to installer to force update using !!!!!   installp -acgFNXYd . X11.fnt.ucs.ttf       !!!!!! and since I'm not using those I didn't care. It's enough for TSM 7.1.6 to be going with installation. Just wanted to everyone else with same problems about solution.